# Struggling trying to read this txt dataset into SAS

Tags: sas

That's the dataset. I need a variable for ShipID, Received, Shipped, City, Zip Code. How would I go about doing that?

This is my first statistical programming language course and I am struggling. My professor hasn't been much of a help either.

```
ShipID  Received   Shipped   Address .   
 X8742 2018/03/14 2018/03/17 Little River, KS, 67457
```

There's a ton more lines and I've been lost on it for an hour.

```
infile "/home/rossfosher0/SAS Homework/SAS Sessions/WarehouseA.txt" firstobs = 2;    
input  @2-7 ShipID $ @9-18 Received: YYYYMMDD8.  @20-28 Shipped: YYYYMMDD8. @City $;    
run;
```

I'm trying to set up a data set for this warehouse.

Comment: This is quite a broad question. What does the code you've supplied do? What data appears in the resulting dataset? Why is it incorrect?

Comment: There is no informat named `yyyymmdd`.  The is one named `yymmdd`.

Answer (score 0):

```
data mydata;   
   input @1 shipid $  @7 received yymmdd10. @18 shipped yymmdd10.  @28 address $30.;   
   format received yymmdd10. shipped yymmdd10.;
datalines;
X8742 2018/03/14 2018/03/17 blue ridge, MA 02391
;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all rows have values for the first three variables you could just read those using list mode input.  Then read the rest of the line as the address.

```
data want;
  infile "..." firstobs=2 truncover;
  input shipid $ received shipped address $50. ;
  informat received shipped yymmdd.;
  format received shipped yymmdd10.;
run;
```

If the data is really in fixed columns then you can use column locations in your INPUT statement, but that is not compatible with using informats.  So either use formatted input for the two date fields or read them as strings.

```
input shipid $1-7 @8 Received yymmdd10. @19 Shipped yymmdd10. Address $ 30-79 ;
format Received Shipped yymmdd10.;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tom and DCR are both right. I prefer an easier route using *Proc import*.

```
 proc import datafile='c:\personal\My_file.csv' 
    out=SAS_data replace;
    DELIMITER=";" ;
    getnames=yes;
    guessingrows= 32767;
 run;
```

What this does is that it makes a guess based on the file read and auto creates the infile-statement. (I just copy it from log and make adjustments if something is read incorrectly.)

If you know the structure of the data follow the other answers, but this is more beginnger friendly approach. (imho) For more see [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n1qn5sclnu2l9dn1w61ifw8wqhts.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)